# Excel VBA: How to add cells in a rows based on matched values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sum values in rows in column B, C, D and E and output the sum values in column k, l, m and n. The criteria is matching the value between column A and J.

The output is not getting the summation correctly for multiple row entries with the same number. For example, for a specific cell value in column A = 32605 that only has one line entry with the following values as input:

```
Pr   Pl  La  Sc
0    1   0   0
```

Output is getting in column K, L, M and N:

```
Pr   Pl  La  Sc
17   0   0   1
```

For the above example, the output should be:

```
Pr   Pl  La  Sc
0    1   0   0
```

For multiple row entries example, Column A cell value = 35092 and the input:

```
Pr  Pl  La Sc
0   1   0   0
0   2   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   3   0   0
0   2   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   1   0   0
84  0   0   7
0   2   0   0
```

Output is showing as:

```
Pr  Pl  La Sc

0   4   0   0
```

The correct output should be:

```
Pr  Pl  La Sc

84  13  0  7
```

Here is the full code

```
Sub A1Report()

  ActiveSheet.Name = "AccessImport"

' Get the start and end date from the user

Dim TheString1 As String, TheString2 As String, TheStartDate As Date, TheEndDate As Date
Dim TotalDaysEntered As Integer



TheString1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the start date:")

If IsDate(TheString1) Then
    TheStartDate = DateValue(TheString1)
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid date entered"
End If


TheString2 = Application.InputBox("Enter the end date:")

If IsDate(TheString2) Then
    TheEndDate = DateValue(TheString2)
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid date entered"
End If

' The following code extracts the data for a specific date range provided by the user.

 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_ARM_Activity_Tracker").Range.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=">=" & TheStartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & TheEndDate

' The next block of code fills up all the blank cells found in column A with E4486 or 004486.

Dim c As Integer

For c = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("A" & c).Value = vbNullString Then
        Range("A" & c).Value = "004486"
    End If
Next c

Columns("A:W").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter


Dim LastRowFrom As Long

Dim LastRowTo As Long

Dim i As Long, j As Long

Dim temp As Long

Dim found As Boolean


'determines the last row that contains data in column A

LastRowFrom = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


' Copy data from active sheet to another sheet

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

ActiveSheet.Name = "DeanRoberts"

Worksheets("AccessImport").Activate

Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook
mainworkBook.Sheets("AccessImport").UsedRange.Copy

mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Select

mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Range("A1").Select

mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Paste


' Find the unique values and place these identified unique values from Column A into Column J

Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Activate

Dim d2 As Object, c2 As Variant, i2 As Long, lr2 As Long

Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

lr2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

c2 = Range("A2:A" & lr2)

For i2 = 1 To UBound(c2, 1)
  d2(c2(i2, 1)) = 1
Next i2

Range("J2").Resize(d2.Count) = Application.Transpose(d2.keys)


' Clear contents after the last rows with values in column J

Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Activate

' Sum values found in column B for each unique WR# in Column J, output the result on Column K, L, M, N

  Dim rowIndex As Long
  Dim calcFormula1 As Double
  Dim calcFormula2 As Double
  Dim calcFormula3 As Double
  Dim calcFormula4 As Double

For rowIndex = 2 To lr2
    calcFormula1 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "*" & Cells(rowIndex, "J").Value & "*", Range("B:B"))
    calcFormula2 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "*" & Cells(rowIndex, "J").Value & "*", Range("C:C"))
    calcFormula3 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "*" & Cells(rowIndex, "J").Value & "*", Range("D:D"))
    calcFormula4 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "*" & Cells(rowIndex, "J").Value & "*", Range("E:E"))

    Cells(rowIndex, "K").Value = calcFormula1
    Cells(rowIndex, "L").Value = calcFormula2
    Cells(rowIndex, "M").Value = calcFormula3
    Cells(rowIndex, "N").Value = calcFormula4

    Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = calcFormula1 + calcFormula2 + calcFormula3 + calcFormula4

Next rowIndex

For rowIndex = 2 To lr2
  Cells(rowIndex, "P").Value = (Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value * 0.008) + 0.08
Next rowIndex


' Sort values, lowest to highest number WR#

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "J:J"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Sort
      .SetRange Range("J:J")
      .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
    End With

Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("O1").Select
Columns("O:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Inserting title of the columns

Cells(1, "J").Value = "WR#"
Cells(1, "K").Value = "Prints"
Cells(1, "L").Value = "Plots"
Cells(1, "M").Value = "Laminate"
Cells(1, "N").Value = "Scans"
Cells(1, "O").Value = "Total Usage"
Cells(1, "P").Value = "Total Hours"

' Cells(1, "P").Value = "Grand Total"

'Cells(2, "P").Value = calcTotal
'avgNumber = calcTotal / TotalDaysEntered

'Cells(1, "Q").Value = "Average"
'Cells(2, "Q").Value = avgNumber


Cells(1, 10).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 11).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 12).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 13).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 14).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 15).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 16).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 17).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 18).Font.Bold = True

Columns("A:W").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

End Sub

Hoping to get your help. Let me know if more info is needed.

Thank you.
mk

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it seems you are trying to use wildcarded 'pattern matches' on numerical values. The

```
Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim calcFormula1 As Double
Dim calcFormula2 As Double
Dim calcFormula3 As Double
Dim calcFormula4 As Double

For rowIndex = 2 To lr2
    calcFormula1 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Value, Range("B:B"))
    calcFormula2 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Value, Range("C:C"))
    calcFormula3 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Value, Range("D:D"))
    calcFormula4 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Value, Range("E:E"))

    Cells(rowIndex, "K").Value = calcFormula1
    Cells(rowIndex, "L").Value = calcFormula2
    Cells(rowIndex, "M").Value = calcFormula3
    Cells(rowIndex, "N").Value = calcFormula4

    Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = calcFormula1 + calcFormula2 + calcFormula3 + calcFormula4

Next rowIndex
```

Your original code was producing false positives by finding *123* inside *91234*.

Your sort routine is taking column J out of synch wiht columns K:O. Substitute what you have for this,

```
' Sort values, lowest to highest number WR#
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DeanRoberts")
    With .Cells(2, 10).CurrentRegion
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End With
```

I would also use the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) property for the sumifs.

```
calcFormula1 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("B:B"))
calcFormula2 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("C:C"))
calcFormula3 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("D:D"))
calcFormula4 = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("E:E"))
```

This should compensate for the leading zeroes found in the numbers-that-are-actually-text.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Jeeped. I have tested the code with your suggestion, but the result seems to be the same, not summing up correctly.

Comment: It would seem that providing a sampling of redacted data would expedite getting to the root of the problem. The data you have provided does not even match the narrative; e.g. where does *35092 * come into play? Suggest you  post a publicly shared link to a workbook with redacted data that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure, I will post a link of the data soon. Just added the full code in the question section.

Comment: Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLiHD7QMfVlU004ODFTRFAwZmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your formulas. You were sorting column J after assigning all the values, but ONLY column J which puts it out of sync with columns K:O. See above for suggested modification(s).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Jeeped. I will get back to you after testing the modified code. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is working now Jeeped. The modified code following your recommendation has resolved the summing issue. Thank you. I am having another issue for calculated formula. Instead of multiplying all cells with 0.008 and then adding 0.08, it is summing it up first, then multiplying 0.008 and adding 0.08. I will edit my original post with this issue. The original summing problem that I had is resolved with your help, now trying to resolve the next issue.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by adding if else if logic. Later today I will post the corrected code so that if anyone else is having the similar issue can also get benefit. I appreciate your help very much Jeeped. I couldn't select "This Answer was useful" as I don't have the access to do it yet per the Stackoverflow message.

Comment: I have uploaded a link to the updated file that has the code in the module: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLiHD7QMfVlZlJzS0VTZXNORlU/view?usp=sharing  Now the problem lies in how the result is getting presented. For example, for a particular WR# the result should be 2.104 but the calculated result is not. Here is a test result doc: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLiHD7QMfVlOVk5Zk13VXdQUlE/view?usp=sharing The purpose of this calculation is to get line entry for each WR# and then use the formula but the resulting calculation not doing this. Hoping to get any help. Thank you.